# Asp.net C# Is there a better way to dynamically assign values based on record count?

Tags: c#

We have Levels 1 - 7 in our table, we'd like to be able to fill this out in c# dynamically, depending on how many levels there are. Currently we have this, but it's a bit messy for me. Is there a better way to do this?

```
switch (OrgPath.Count)
{
    case 1:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 2:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 3:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 4:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 5:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 6:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = OrgPath[6].LevelNodeId;
        break;
    case 7: 
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = OrgPath[6].LevelNodeId;
        budgetRequest.Level7NodeId = OrgPath[7].LevelNodeId;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, I'd recommend trying to redesign your `budgetRequest` class to use a collection of IDs. However, even if that's not possible in your situation, you can still keep your code relatively clean.

The simple method -- get rid of the switch and just use a series of `if` statements:

```
if (OrgPath.Count >= 1)
  budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 2)
  budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 3)
  budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 4)
  budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 5)
  budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 6)
  budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = OrgPath[6].LevelNodeId;
if (OrgPath.Count >= 7)
  budgetRequest.Level7NodeId = OrgPath[7].LevelNodeId;
```

Or a more advanced method -- use an array of setters:

```
var setters = new Action<string>[] {
    x => budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = x,
    x => budgetRequest.Level7NodeId = x,
};

for (var i = 0; i < OrgPath.Count; i++) {
    setters[i](OrgPath[i + 1].LevelNodeId);
}
```

Going a bit too far -- use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) (I don't actually recommend this as it's a bit confusing, brittle, and not particularly performant):

```
for (var i = 0; i < OrgPath.Count; i++) {
    var property = typeof(BudgetRequest).GetProperty($"Level{i + 1}NodeId");
    property.SetValue(budgetRequest, OrgPath[i + 1].LevelNodeId);
}
```

Comment: I'll go for the simple method just because it's easier to maintain, thank you

Comment: This is THE answer, but wouldn't `if (OrgPath.Count >= 1)
  budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;` fail if the OrgPath had 1 element?

Comment: @tymtam I assume you mean because for array (and most other collections) indexes start at zero. Yes, you could be right, however, there are some situations where you might still have to interact with a system or library that uses base-1 collections. I'm making the assumption that OP's original code was correct when offsetting the index of `OrgPath` by 1. This *might* be another issue with OP's code but it seems to be outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having an explicit property for every level (`Level1NodeId`, `Level2NodeId`, etc) make a `Dictionary<int, WhatverTypeId>` property:

```
public Dictionary<int, WhateverTypeId> LevelNodeIds { get; set; }
```

This gives you an added bonus to dynamically support more levels later on, and makes your code *truly* dynamic (and much shorter):

```
for(int i = 0; i < OrgPath.Count; i++)
{
    budgetRequest.LevelNodeIds.Add(i, OrgPath[i].LevelNodeId;
}
```

And when you need to access an id by level remember arrays are zero based in C#:

```
budgetRequest.LevelNodeIds[0] // accesses level 1
budgetRequest.LevelNodeIds[1] // accesses level 2
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

## Note on indexes

C#'s collections use indexing starting from 0.

```
switch (OrgPath.Count)
{
    case 1:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId;
```

may need to be changed to

```
switch (OrgPath.Count)
{
    case 1:
        budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[0].LevelNodeId;
```

## A. If BudgetRequest can be changed

The budget request class could store the level node ids in a collection.

Consider the following snippet.

```
class BudgetRequest {
    public int[] LevelNodeIds {get; set;}
}

(...)

var budgetRequest = new BudgetRequest() 
{
    LevelNodeIds = new int[OrgPath.Count]
};
for(int i = 0; i < OrgPath.Count; i++) {
    budgetRequest.LevelNodeIds[i] = OrgPath[i].LevelNodeId;
}
```

## B. If BudgetRequest cannot be changed.

@p-s-w-g's `if` solution is the way to go, but it's possible to make the code look nicer and keep the `switch`.

(Please note I for level 7 I used OrgPath[6], because of zero-based indexes, you may adjust this)

```
switch (OrgPath.Count)
{
    case 7: budgetRequest.Level7NodeId = OrgPath[6].LevelNodeId; goto case 6;
    case 6: budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId; goto case 5;
    case 5: budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId; goto case 4;
    case 4: budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId; goto case 3;
    case 3: budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId; goto case 2;
    case 2: budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId; goto case 1;
    case 1: budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[0].LevelNodeId; break;
    default: goto case 7;
}
```

Example

```
var OrgPath = new[]{
    new { LevelNodeId = "A1" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "B2" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "C3" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "D4" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "E5" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "F6" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "G7" },
    new { LevelNodeId = "H8" },
}.ToList();

var budgetRequest = new BudgetRequest();
switch (OrgPath.Count)
{
    case 7: budgetRequest.Level7NodeId = OrgPath[6].LevelNodeId; goto case 6;
    case 6: budgetRequest.Level6NodeId = OrgPath[5].LevelNodeId; goto case 5;
    case 5: budgetRequest.Level5NodeId = OrgPath[4].LevelNodeId; goto case 4;
    case 4: budgetRequest.Level4NodeId = OrgPath[3].LevelNodeId; goto case 3;
    case 3: budgetRequest.Level3NodeId = OrgPath[2].LevelNodeId; goto case 2;
    case 2: budgetRequest.Level2NodeId = OrgPath[1].LevelNodeId; goto case 1;
    case 1: budgetRequest.Level1NodeId = OrgPath[0].LevelNodeId; break;
    default: goto case 7;
}

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(budgetRequest, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions{WriteIndented = true}));
```

Output

```
{
  "Level1NodeId": "A1",
  "Level2NodeId": "B2",
  "Level3NodeId": "C3",
  "Level4NodeId": "D4",
  "Level5NodeId": "E5",
  "Level6NodeId": "F6",
  "Level7NodeId": "G7"
}
```

Comment: I feel really dumb at the end of this long day... my answer uses a Dictionary and I just realized there is absolutely no need haha

Comment: Because `BudgetRequest` is a table with explicit column names like `Level1NodeId`, `Level2NodeId`, etc. Don't we have to assign it explicitly by the name?